# Draw a line from BottomLeft To TopRight with TLine

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is it possible to draw a diagonal line that runs from Bottomleft to Topright or the other way around.

I can only draw lines from TopLeft to BottomRight.

The Linetype is set to ltDiagonal. The line is always drawn from TopLeft To BottomRight

If set a negative width (bottomright is left of TopLeft), the Tline is not drawn, because the width is set to 0.

```
Tline(Control).LineType:=TLineType.ltDiagonal;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use RotationAngle property. Set it to 90 and the line will be drawn from BottomLeft to TopRight, as well as size dimensions will swap.

Comment: This feels more like a workaround. But maybe it is the only solution. I thought I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the utility function I created to handle this situation for any two points. The TLine must be set to diagonal.

```
  //------------------------------------------------------------------
  // DrawLineBetweenPoints
  // TLine component draws a line bound by a rectangular box. The default
  // line goes low to high when set as a diagonal, so we need to do the 
  // math to make it handle the other quadrant possibilities.
  //------------------------------------------------------------------
  procedure DrawLineBetweenPoints(L: TLine; p1, p2: TPointF);
  begin
    L.LineType := TLineType.Diagonal;
    L.RotationCenter.X := 0.0;
    L.RotationCenter.Y := 0.0;
    if (p2.X >= p1.X) then begin
      // Line goes left to right, what about vertical?
      if (p2.Y > p1.Y) then begin
        // Case #1 - Line goes high to low, so NORMAL DIAGONAL
        L.RotationAngle := 0;
        L.Position.X := p1.X;
        L.Width := p2.X - p1.X;
        L.Position.Y := p1.Y;
        L.Height := p2.Y - p1.Y;
      end else begin
        // Case #2 - Line goes low to high, so REVERSE DIAGONAL
        // X and Y are now upper left corner and width and height reversed
        L.RotationAngle := -90;
        L.Position.X := p1.X;
        L.Width := p1.Y - p2.Y;
        L.Position.Y := p1.Y;
        L.Height := p2.X - p1.X;
      end;
    end else begin
      // Line goes right to left
      if (p1.Y > p2.Y) then begin
        // Case #3 - Line goes high to low (but reversed) so NORMAL DIAGONAL
        L.RotationAngle := 0;
        L.Position.X := p2.X;
        L.Width := p1.X - p2.X;
        L.Position.Y := p2.Y;
        L.Height := p1.Y - p2.Y;
      end else begin
        // Case #4 - Line goes low to high, REVERSE DIAGONAL
        // X and Y are now upper left corner and width and height reversed
        L.RotationAngle := -90;
        L.Position.X := p2.X;
        L.Width := p2.Y - p1.Y;
        L.Position.Y := p2.Y;
        L.Height := p1.X - p2.X;
      end;
    end;
    if (L.Height < 0.01) then L.Height := 0.1;
    if (L.Width < 0.01) then L.Width := 0.1;
  end;
```